# How do i create a gem which will generate a css file from a template

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a set of css files which I use in almost all projects.
I would like to create a gem which has a generator inside it.
I managed to write some code using the tutorial given here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

However i am not sure about how to move this to a gem and use a command like device install ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two ways of doing this (and both involve a Rails Engine afaik).

- You create a engine that contains a generator for your file
- You create a engine that bundles the CSS file so you can require it without having it present in your code repository. (Similar to the jQuery gem).

To create an engine just follow this guide: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html.
Just without the mountable option and anything you put inside your `app/assets/stylesheet` directory will be available through `require` inside your CSS manifest.
The relevant part in the guide is in 6.4 besides the general boilerplate setup you have to do.

For a generateor the same applies, you just have to put the generator in the generators directory as you would with the app and can then run it from there with the engine prefix.

Comment: I think this is what i am looking for. in fact i never gave a though on engines. Thank you for your quick reply. i will do this today...

Comment: Glad I could help .. I haven't tried to much around so far besides bundling a asset with the engine as I thought we need that for an app at work .. Sorry I can't give you specific instructions on what steps to do exactly .. I was mostly googling my way around when I tried that out last time..

Comment: Its OK. I am looking into it now. I am interested in the first way using generators as that will give the end user a chance to alter the css files generated.